When using cucumber in androidTest I have no access to classes in main folder
I use Cucumber for my android tests (in 'androidTest' folder). I start a test of a feature file. During the test (cucumber-step) I call a function which is located in the 'main' folder and not in the 'androidTest' folder of my project. This does not work and I get the following error:

Step failed
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError

When I start a normal junit test, then this works.
It seems that I can only access classes and functions within the 'androidTest' folder when using cucumber.
Any ideas?
